# How to set metalness as a float value when using PBRLightingModel in SceneKit?

Tags: scenekit

In Xcode 8, the *SceneKit Editor* allows you to set a float value for the  metalness property when using **SCNLightingModelPhysicallyBased**. The options are Metallic, Dielectric, Float Value or an image.  Choosing Metallic sets metalness to 1. Choosing Dielectric sets it to 0.

[image: Metalness Scene Kit Editor]

What is the programmatic equivalent of setting **metalness** to 1 (as allowed in *SceneKit Editor*)? 
metalness is a read only property.  So, is my only choice to set the  someMaterial.metalness.contents to a **metalness** map image?

Comment: OK - setting the contents to [UIColor blackColor] worked.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some material properties such as `metalness` and `roughness` accept a `NSNumber` for their `contents`.

```
// Objective-C
material.roughness.contents = @0.5;
```

```
// Swift
material.roughness.contents = NSNumber(value: 0.5)
```

It looks like the online documentation hasn't caught that yet, but the header doc for `SCNMaterialProperty` has this information.